# Como ordenar un objeto de acuerdo a su key?

Tags: javascript

tengo un objeto que necesito ordenar, me interesa definir el orden de unos 4 por lo menos los demás podrían ordenarse de forma como queden, decir que este objeto no siempre viene en el mismo orden es por ello mi consulta.

```
{ 
  gratificacionZona:7500 //Quinto
  leyNoDocente:"28000" 
  sueldoBase:50000 //Primero
  sueldoGeneral:0 //Segundo
  sueldoPIE:0   //Tercero
  sueldoSEP:0  //Cuarto
}
```

a veces este objeto puede traer mas parametros , pero solo me interesa el orden de estos marcados.

este codigo ingresa los item al arreglo que necesito.

```
   _.forEach(liquidacion.imponible, function(value,key){
                aa.table.body.push([{ text: key , border: [true, false, false, false] }, { text: value , border: [false, false, true, false] }]);

            })
```

Answer (score 2):

Como tal no hay una forma de ordenar los atributos de un objeto en javascript, para eso te tienes que valer ciertas funciones o métodos para lograrlo:

```
Object.keys(data).sort()
  .forEach(function(item, i) {
      console.log(item, data[item]);
   });  // Donde data es tu objeto
```

Esta puede ser una forma, cuando ordenas de mayor a menor, alfabéticamente, etc.

En tu caso, necesitarías de una lista de ayuda, las cuales si conservan su orden, de esta forma:

```
let order = ['sueldoBase', 'sueldoGeneral', 'sueldoPIE', 'sueldoESP', 'gratificacionZona']
order.forEach(function(item, i) {
    console.log(item, data[item]);
});  // Donde data es tu objeto
```

Cualquier duda comenta.
[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658690/is-there-a-way-to-sort-order-keys-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: me gusta, ahora edite el código ya que el orden debe quedar antes establecido en el objeto para luego en el forEach agregar objetos al arreglo ya ordenado

Answer (score 2):

Usando ES6:

```js
let objeto = { 
  gratificacionZona:7500,
  leyNoDocente:"28000", 
  sueldoBase:50000, //Primero
  sueldoGeneral:0, //Segundo
  sueldoPIE:0,   //Tercero
  sueldoSEP:0  //Cuarto
}

objeto = {
  sueldoBase:objeto.sueldoBase, //Primero
  sueldoGeneral:objeto.sueldoGeneral, //Segundo
  sueldoPIE:objeto.sueldoPIE,   //Tercero
  sueldoSEP:objeto.sueldoSEP,  //Cuarto
  ...objeto
}

console.log(objeto)
```

De la antigua forma (BabelJS mediante):

```js
"use strict";

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var objeto = {
  gratificacionZona: 7500,
  leyNoDocente: "28000",
  sueldoBase: 50000, //Primero
  sueldoGeneral: 0, //Segundo
  sueldoPIE: 0, //Tercero
  sueldoSEP: 0 //Cuarto
};

objeto = _extends({
  sueldoBase: objeto.sueldoBase, //Primero
  sueldoGeneral: objeto.sueldoGeneral, //Segundo
  sueldoPIE: objeto.sueldoPIE, //Tercero
  sueldoSEP: objeto.sueldoSEP }, objeto);
  
console.log(objeto)
```

Comment: en lodash seria _. merge ?

Comment: El problema con _.merge es que te reemplaza los valores que asignaste antes, de manera que perdes el orden